# Read address value from kernel using /dev/kmem

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

Trying to read kernel address value (task_struct)

Wrote this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define addr 0xe6d63a80

extern int errno;

int main()
{
        int i;
        unsigned char *kmem;
        unsigned char val;

        int fd = open("/dev/kmem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
        if(fd < 0)
        {
                printf("Can't open /dev/kmem\n");
                return 1;
        }
        kmem = (unsigned char *) mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0xe6d63000);
        if(kmem == NULL)
        {
                printf("Can't mmap\n");
                return 1;
        }
        else
                printf("kmem=%p\n",kmem);


        return 0;
}
```

But it produces:

```
kmem=0xffffffff
```

Which does not look like a valid pointer to values of memory.

How to read content of kernel memory? In this case: 0xe6d63a80. I know task_struct is there, since I verified it with the debugger.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `mmap` returning -1. You've assigned the value and are printingit as unsigned, though, so that is why you are seeing `0xffffffff`. You should check for `mmap` returning and error and then check `errno` for the cause.

```
    kmem = (unsigned char *) mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0xe6d63000);
    if (kmem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Error mapping memory");
        return -1;
    }
```

Check out the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

Comment: Thanks! Well I got now: "Error mapping memory: Invalid argument" Why is it invalid? I know the address is correct and there is data there (verified with gdb)

Comment: @android_dev Sorry, I don't have enough info to know what is going on!