# Processing entries from task_struct. Why some tasks->next have 0. How to go to next task than?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I know about Kernel module macro for_each_process

```
struct task_struct *iter; 
for_each_process(iter)
{ 
if (iter->state > 0)
{ 
  snprintf(buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE, " name: %s, pid: %d, parent id: %d, state: %ld", iter->group_leader->comm, iter->pid, iter->parent->pid, iter->state);
  print_string(buf); 
}
```

It should go through task_struct tasks members and get the next member of tasks which is task_struct.

Wrote this userland program, that should do the same:

list-tasks.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



long readtaskstruct(long address)
{

    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;

    long addr = address; 
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char nextstr;
    int page_size,offset;


    addrp = (long *) addr;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val;

    offset = addr & 0xfff;



    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd,ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {



        memcpy(&val,retp+(offset+784),4); //tasks next pointer
        val = val-620; //address to task_struct 
        munmap(retp,4096);

        close(fd);


    }

    return val;
}           


const char * readval(long address)
{                
    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;


    long addr = address;
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char *nextstr = calloc(sizeof(char),100);
    int page_size,offset;

    long *nextp = (long *) next;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = next & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val; 

    offset = next & 0xfff;
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);

    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {

        memcpy(nextstr,retp+(offset+996),100); //task->comm



        munmap(retp,4096);
    }
        return nextstr;
}
void main(void)
{


int ret = 0xc1a8cac0; //init_task

ret = readtaskstruct(ret);
printf("%s\n",readval(ret));




}
```

It works.

```
$./list-tasks
swapper/0
```

However, when I call it recursively, i.e:

```
  int ret = 0xc1a8cac0; //init_task

  while(1)
  {  
    ret = readtaskstruct(ret);
    printf("%s\n",readval(ret));
  }
```

It goes through first task->next and than somehow it seems that task->next is set to 0, since I get ret as 0.

Why some tasks->next have 0 ... I though I should see a nice list of processes linking in tasks from one to the other. Why it breaks with 0 after first process.

Anybody sees logical/programming error in list-tasks.c?

**Update 1:**

hmmm .. it seems to work correctly with for_each_process: more info https://0bin.net/paste/HCkEu8+daKo9Y8Z3#+M0vkO9KmtSmBSXBnuvQi73NsU2hrq0gWzJ6U8IHU4s. Is my understanding correct that tasks member of structure task_struct will have members next and prev which point to task_structs?

hmm my init_task is at 0xc1a8cac0 ... why I dont see it in for_each_process output from kernel module?

ok so it is not listed there and than it links to next as 0xf58c0318 ...
and this links next to 0x0

just checked with GDB

my question is why init_task is not listed in for_each_process macro?

I guess I start with wrong process and the list ends ....

**Update 2:**

Live debugs

https://0bin.net/paste/h6YqUUQnKpIIPSMO#1mxZ5RR9zPIrbNOykeWHju58WZ-lOKhYhjaNnn/YEiq

Modified the list-task.c to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



long readtaskstruct(long address)
{

    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;

    long addr = address; 
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char nextstr;
    int page_size,offset;


    addrp = (long *) addr;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val;

    offset = addr & 0xfff;



    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd,ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {



        memcpy(&val,retp+(offset+620),4); //tasks next pointer
        //val = val-620; //address to task_struct 
        munmap(retp,4096);

        close(fd);


    }

    return val;
}           


const char * readval(long address)
{                
    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;


    long addr = address;
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char *nextstr = calloc(sizeof(char),100);
    int page_size,offset;

    long *nextp = (long *) next;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val; 

    offset = next & 0xfff;
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);

    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {

        memcpy(nextstr,retp+(offset+996),100); //task->comm



        munmap(retp,4096);
    }
    return nextstr;
}
void main(void)
{


    int ret = 0xc1a8cac0; //init_task

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("0x%x\n",ret);
        ret = readtaskstruct(ret);
        printf("%s\n",readval(ret));
    }


}
```

**Update 3:**

Sweet works.

```
./list-task  |more
Address:0xc1a8cac0
Process:systemd
Address:0xf58b8000
Process:kthreadd
Address:0xf58b89c0
Process:ksoftirqd/0
Address:0xf58b9380
Process:kworker/0:0H
Address:0xf58ba700
Process:rcu_sched
Address:0xf58bba80
Process:rcu_bh
Address:0xf58bc440
Process:migration/0
Address:0xf58bce00
Process:migration/1
Address:0xf58bf500
Process:ksoftirqd/1
Address:0xf58f0000
Process:kworker/1:0H
Address:0xf58f1380
Process:migration/2
Address:0xf58f1d40
Process:ksoftirqd/2
Address:0xf58f2700
Process:kworker/2:0H
Address:0xf58f3a80
Process:migration/3
Address:0xf58f4440
Process:ksoftirqd/3
Address:0xf58f4e00
Process:kworker/3:0H
Address:0xf58f6180
Process:kdevtmpfs
Address:0xf5948000
Process:netns
Address:0xf59b0000
Process:kworker/u8:1
.
.
.
Process:VBoxClient
Address:0xf594d7c0
Process:VBoxClient
Address:0xf0f0e180
Process:VBoxClient
Address:0xf513b0c0
FAILED
FAILED
Process:
Address:0x3513b000
FAILED
FAILED
Process:
Address:0x3513b000
```

list-task.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



long readtaskstruct(long address)
{

    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;

    long addr = address; 
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char nextstr;
    int page_size,offset;


    addrp = (long *) addr;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val;

    offset = addr & 0xfff;



    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096*4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd,ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {



        memcpy(&val,retp+(offset+620),4); //tasks next pointer
        if(val==0)
          return 0;
        val = val-620; //address to task_struct 
        munmap(retp,4096*4);

        close(fd);


    }

    return val;
}           


const char * readval(long address)
{                
    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;


    long addr = address;
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char *nextstr = calloc(sizeof(char),100);
    int page_size,offset;

    long *nextp = (long *) next;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val; 

    offset = addr & 0xfff;
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096*4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {

        memcpy(nextstr,retp+(offset+996),100); //task->comm



        munmap(retp,4096*4);
    }
    return nextstr;
}
void main(void)
{


    int ret = 0xc1a8cac0; //init_task

    while(1)
    {
        if(ret!=0)
        {
          printf("Address:0x%x\n",ret);
          ret = readtaskstruct(ret);
          printf("Process:%s\n",readval(ret));
        }else{
          break;
        }
    }


}
```

How will I know however that the list is at the end? Now it fails with mmap, that's how I know it is done. Is there any better, eleganter way to tell it?

Thanks,

**Update 4:**

Final version:

list-task.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



long readtaskstruct(long address)
{

    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;

    long addr = address; 
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char nextstr;
    int page_size,offset;


    addrp = (long *) addr;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val;

    offset = addr & 0xfff;



    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096*4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd,ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {



        memcpy(&val,retp+(offset+620),4); //tasks next pointer
        if(val==0)
          return 0;
        val = val-620; //address to task_struct 
        munmap(retp,4096*4);

        close(fd);


    }

    return val;
}           


const char * readval(long address)
{                
    int fd;
    void *retp = NULL;


    long addr = address;
    long *addrp = NULL;

    long next,prev;
    long val;
    char *nextstr = calloc(sizeof(char),100);
    int page_size,offset;

    long *nextp = (long *) next;
    page_size = getpagesize();
    val = addr & ~(page_size-1)- 0xc0000000;
    long *ptr = (long *) val; 

    offset = addr & 0xfff;
    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    retp = mmap(NULL, 4096*4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, ptr);


    if (retp == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
    }
    else
    {

        memcpy(nextstr,retp+(offset+996),100); //task->comm



        munmap(retp,4096*4);
    }
    return nextstr;
}
void main(void)
{


    int ret = 0xc1a8cac0; //init_task

    do
    {
          //printf("Address:0x%x\n",ret);
          ret = readtaskstruct(ret);
          printf("Process:%s\n",readval(ret));
    }while(ret!=0 && ret!= 0xc1a8cac0);


}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Added some Debug info. See Update 1: I think I narrowed the issue. My question is why init_task is not listed in for_each_process macro? I guess I start with wrong process and the list ends ....

Comment: Recheck the offsets (784 and 620). The first should be equal to `offsetof(struct task_struct, tasks.next)`, the second should be equal to `offsetof(struct task_struct, tasks)`. But since `.next` is the first field of `tasks`, both offsets should be the same. You may write a kernel module which prints values of expressions above, so you will be sure about the offsets.

Comment: `why init_task is not listed in for_each_process macro?` - According to [implementation](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L503) of `for_each_process`, it starts from `init_task`. Probably, this task doesn't pass your `if` condition.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Big thanks for your explanations. I verified both offsets are 620. I put more info in Update 2:

Comment: Still stops, I assume tasks.next  becomes 0. But why?

Comment: Why a line `val = val-620; //address to task_struct` is commented out?

Comment: @Tsyvarev BIG THANKS!!! Sweet! Works .... how will I know the list is at the end? Now I catch it with mmap failure

Comment: If you look into `for_each_process` macro, you will find that it stops to iterate when `.next` pointer points to the `init_task`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Perfect. Works. Updated the code Update 4:

Comment: 620 and 996 are very system dependent... I have 2 arm machine (one rea and one emulated with qemu) and the structures are different in BOTH. Any way to get the offset from some include file or structure?

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/mem` gives you access to the physical memory of the system. The m[em(4) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) explains more about what `/dev/mem` is. In your code, you are assuming that the first page of physical memory is the first page of kernel memory and using a fixed offset you will get to the `init_task`. The kernel image may be loaded at some offset of physical RAM instead of start of RAM depending on the platform.

You can use `/dev/kmem` to access the kernel virtual memory, but again you need to know the proper page and offset where you will find `init_task` structure, which may vary.

> > my init_task is at 0xc1a8cac0 ... why I dont see it in for_each_process output from kernel module?

You should have guessed that your address of `init_task` is incorrect rater than speculating why init_task is not in the task_list.

I recommend that you write a simple kernel module and access the `init_task` variable directly without any pointer arithmetic.

If you look at the macro `for_each_process`, you will notice that it infact starts with `init_task` and loops the circular task list back to `init_task`

```
#define for_each_process(p) \
        for (p = &init_task ; (p = next_task(p)) != &init_task ; )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I verified init_task address from Kernel Symbols and GDB. I would love to use /dev/kmem... but wasnt able to make it work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370376/read-address-value-from-kernel-using-dev-kmem/48370431#48370431 Hence I Use /dev/mem :(